# How can I match \n\r with preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove the empty paragraphs in html:

```
<p>
</p>
```

use `/<p>\n\r<\/p>/` can't match this
while use `/<p>.{0,2}<\/p>/` works, why?

Comment: `/<p>.{0,2}<\/p>/` cannot match linebreaks, you must be using `/<p>.{0,2}<\/p>/s`

Comment: You can use [escape  sequence `\R`](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#newlineseq) to match CR, LF but also the sequence CR LF ([see demo](https://eval.in/668902)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need a new line, `\r` (return) comes before `\n` (new), so in your expression you should use `\r\n`.

Comment: Or `/[\r\n]+/` for example